# libVLC C library: Disable generation of album art cache programmatically

Tags: c, libvlc

I have written a simple command-line based audio player in C using libVLC library. Every time a audio file is played, an album art (.jpg format) and a directory in the track's name will be created for each track, inside '~/.cache/vlc' folder which is taking up significant disk space and creating lots of directories. I have thousands of tracks and this is becoming a concern. Need help on disabling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found around this knotty little issue was to create the directory `$HOME/.cache/vlc/art` and simply make it **read only**.
If vlc can't write to it:
a. The issue disappears
b. vlc doesn't complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

Album art seems to be a long-standing problem with VLC (judging by the threads on their user forum).  If you are using the most recent version (~3.0.0), adding this startup option might help:

```
--no-metadata-network-access
```

By all descriptions, this should prevent libVLC from **downloading** the album art.  However, there are indications that if the album art is **embedded** in the audio (.mp3 file, etc.) then the album art may still get extracted to your drive.  I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent that.